# Can you a get bash script traceback from another language?

Tags: bash, python, trace

If I have a script, lets call it "scr.sh" 
And I call it from another language e.g Python
Is there a way to get the traceback of the functions and files back to the Python language.

How I think it could possibly work:
the scr.sh

```
echo "something"
echo `get_traceback` > "/tmp/traceback" 
echo "something else
```

And a python script  "scr2.py"

```
if __name__ == '__main__'
    self.call_func()

def call_func(self):
    import subprocess
    print "some"
    subprocess.call("scr.sh")
    print "thing"
```

Can I get the traceback the from the bash script back to the python script? I'd expect that if it exists it would look like this:

```
file /tmp/scr2.py , line 2 in function "main",
file /tmp/scr2.py , line 7 in function "call_func", 
bash file /tmp/scr.sh, line 2
```

Comment: does `bash -x scr.sh` help?

Comment: No, this is going to get the trace of the bash file commands. I don't need that. I ask if it is possible to get the trace back to the originating caller of the script.

Comment: You'd have to generate the python part of the traceback before calling the bash script, and you'll have to make it available to bash (using the environment would be simplest)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hoping to not have to do. The problem is that the bash script could be called from a number of places, and I need to find out from where exactly. Thanks anyway